# update list to recyclerview adapter with DiffUtil removing the old one?

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm using DiffUtil for my RecyclerView and it works fine for one loading list but when try to use it with to update new list to the current list it removes the old data
here is my adapter

```
class SettingRecyclerView(private val interaction: Interaction? = null) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SettingItem>() {

        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: SettingItem, newItem: SettingItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SettingItem, newItem: SettingItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.hashCode() == newItem.hashCode()
        }

    }
    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, DIFF_CALLBACK)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        return SettingViewHolder(
            ItemRvBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            ),
            interaction
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is SettingViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(differ.currentList.get(position))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    fun submitList(list: List<SettingItem>) {
        differ.submitList(list)
    }

    class SettingViewHolder
    constructor(
        private val binding: ItemRvBinding,
        private val interaction: Interaction?
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(item: SettingItem) = with(binding.root) {
            binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                interaction?.onItemSelected(adapterPosition, item)
            }

            binding.settingTitle.text = item.title

        }
    }

    interface Interaction {
        fun onItemSelected(position: Int, item: SettingItem)
    }
}
```

Here is how I update the list in my Activity

```
lateinit var mAdapter: SettingRecyclerView

mAdapter.submitList(settings)
```

I didn't know what's the problem exactly which makes that problem, is there a way else to update the list with DiffUtil or I must use notifiydatachanged or what?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are not using `data class` it will cause a problem.**

The problem is that you are comparing the `SettingItem.hashCode()` in `areContentsTheSame()` method.

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SettingItem, newItem: SettingItem): Boolean {
    \\ You need to pass the same object to evaluate to true.
    return oldItem.hashCode() == newItem.hashCode()
}
```

Solution:

You need to use `data class` in the right way so the compiler automatically derives the `hashCode()` and `equals()` from all properties declared in the primary constructor.

See this: [Data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#top)

Or you should compare `SettingsItem`'s properties manually.